# Unwanted annotation boxes under animation nodes

Tags: animation, node-editor, annotation

Please help, I have somehow activated these annotation boxes beneath my animation nodes and can't find any reasoning as to how I remove them or what the even are. :([image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a developper option: in the property panel on the right (<kbd>N</kbd>):

Select the "NodeTree" tab, then go to the "Developer" section and set "Execution code" from "Measure Execution Times" to "Default".

[image]

As its name tells, this is to see the measures of execution time for each node.

Comment: Wow a king  thanks a ton  hope you have a great week!